# Optimization of Rectangle-based Point Search

Tags: java, search, optimization, hashmap, interval-tree

I have a set of rooms and passages that I can convert into Rectangles (x,y,width,height) or a list of Points (x,y). `Room` and `Passage` both extend the `Pointable` interface. The getPoints() method is implemented for the Room class as

```
public Set<Point> getPoints() {
    Set<Point> array = new HashSet<Point>();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            array.add(new Point(x + i, y + j));
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

**The Problem:**
I must identify the `Pointable` that a given `Point` belongs to. No rooms intersect. I originally used a `HashMap<Point,Pointable>` to correlate each `Point` to a `Pointable`, which was able to quickly able to access the answer in O(n) time. However, it is now necessary to recalculate the `HashMap` multiple times in the generation of a level.
*At this point, is it still more efficient to use the HashMap (in consideration of generation and access) or should another method be used, such as a set of 2-D interval trees?*

Comment: You might be able to implement an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) for this.

Comment: The only problem I might have with a R-Tree would be due to the long passages, which would increase the sizes of the rectangles and decrease efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point, is it still more efficient to use the HashMap (in consideration of generation and access) or should another method be used, such as a set of 2-D interval trees?

Nobody can tell except the one who did a measurement. It all depends on how often you need to update the data, how often they change, and how often they get queried.

And also on the size of a `Room`. With a few points, the `HashMap` wins in a typical scenario, with thousands of them, the overhead of updating the points dominates.

---

Can't you use an array for all `Point`s? If so, then it'll be surely way faster then the `HashMap`, especially for updating (unless it gets really huge).

---

*This may or may not be useful.*

Actually, not only each `Room` has some `Point`s, but also each `Point` may have one `Room` (n:1). How it gets implemented, it's a different question.

Given this, we have a standard problem: If you link bidirectionally, then you have to keep both links in sync. The simplest solution is to make the setters ("adders"/"removers") as private as possible and only called them from a method

```
void link(Room room, Point point) {
    Room oldRoom = point.getRoom();
    if (oldRoom!=null) oldRoom.removePoint(point);
    room.addPoint(point);
    point.setRoom(room);
}
```

Your linking from `Point` to `Room` is external, but this hardly changes anything (except for keeping `Point` smaller and possibly cleaner and adding the tiny overhead of a HashMap to each access).

It's usually also the fastest as usually there are much more queries than updates. Your problem is that the update cost gets scaled up by the `Room` size. **Without you telling us some figures, no estimate is possible.**

---

With too many points and rooms of not too widely varying size, you could round the point coordinates to a multiple of some `n` and keep an array holding the set of all rooms intersecting  the grid. You could proceed as before, but the update overhead would be lower by nearly a factor given by the room area(*) and the search overhead higher, as you'd have to select the really matching room (if any) from the set.

(*) For rooms not aligned to grid, the number of intersecting rectangles is obviously higher.